# Copying values of 2D array into another

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array that I want to assign the values of another array. I'm making a game of life simulator and have everything else working but this. My code is this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; i < COLS; j++) {
            current[i][j] = next[i][j];
        }
    }
```

current and next are both bool's. I keep getting the error code EXC_BAD_ACCESS in X-Code. I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: [post on how to debug this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-is-exc_bad_access-and-how-to-debug-it--cms-24544). I personally think it might be that you check for `i < COLS`, which means j becomes massive. (so current[i][j] goes out of bounds)

Comment: Agree with WorkofArtiz, second line should be `j < COLS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To re-iterate my comment, the innerloop compares `i` with `COL` rather than `j`. So

```
for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
        current[i][j] = next[i][j];
    }
}
```

should solve the issue

Comment: Thank you! That was a very stupid mistake, don't know why I didn't catch it